# How can get the exact touch position of a SKShapeNode?

Tags: ios, swift, touch, skspritenode

If a shape is rectangle, the touch position is exactly right. but if a shape contains transparent area (like triangle below), when user tap on the transparent area(it's empty space on the screen), the touch is also valid.

[image]

When there are many shapes on screen, user may tap on the right position but get the wrong shape. For example, if a user want to choose the green triangle and tap on the red dot, but the selected shape will be pink triangle because the pink triangle's zPosition is upper than green triangle, and the touch position is inside pink triangle's transparent area.

[image]

Here is the codes to create shape when begin:

```
var touchShapeName:String!
var currShape: SKShapeNode!
var shapeArr = [SKShapeNode]()
```

creat shapes:

```
    for i in 1...count {
    let shape = SKShapeNode()
    shape.path = petalPath
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.7, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1.0)
    shape.lineWidth = 0.1
    shape.glowWidth = 0.1
    shape.fillColor = UIColor(red: getRandomColor(245, 255), green: getRandomColor(190, 210), blue: getRandomColor(10, 15), alpha: 0.98)
    shape.name = "\(i)"
    shape.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX + CGFloat( 30 * i ), y:frame.midY + 60)
    addChild(shape)
shapArr.append(shape)
}
```

I use the following codes to get the shape:

```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let location = touch?.location(in: self)
        touchShapeName = self.atPoint(location!).name
        if currShape == nil{
            for s in shapeArr{
                if s.name == touchShapeName{
                    currShape = s
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**By now, the shapes can be created and moved when tap on color area. Problem is that tapping on the shape with a upper transparent area may get the wrong shape as I explain above.**

Do I write the right codes? Is any other solution to get the exact position?

Thx.

Comment: Yes, it is the right code to get exact location. Though you may not clicked the actual image I mean the green image but according to screen the clicked portion gives you the exact point.

Comment: Agree with @poles. In addition, if what you need is the coordinates of the touch relative to the green shape, see the method convert(_:​to:​) in SKNode.

Comment: @AliBeadle can tell how to get it with method convert(_:to:)? I tried currShape = SKShapeNode()
        convert(location!, to: currShape)
        print(currShape.name), but it printed nil.

Comment: @jdleung You call convert on the SKNode instance that the point is currently in (in your case this will be the scene - which is an SKNode) and pass it the instance that you want the coordinate to be in. The result is another coordinate. So: let newPoint = convert(location!, to: currShape) print(newPoint) (but I really don't like force unwrapping location like that - look into safer optional unwrapping techniques).

Comment: @AliBeadle sorry, I still cannot get the shape with lower zPosition. ;-(

Comment: You need to post a new question, wth your code and results so far and a specific question.

Comment: @AliBeadle I edited the question and posted my trying codes. BTW, what I need is to get the green triangle( marked with name ) by tapping the red dot. Thx.

Comment: let shape = SKShapeNode() will always return a null name and position, how could it not? You have not given that new shape a name or position (or for that matter a shape). What do you expect it to contain? I think you are missing some fundamental details on how SpriteKit and Swift work and need to go back to some more basic examples.

Comment: @AliBeadle the shapes have been created with name, I need to get the shape and it's name when it's tapped. it seems your method only returns CGRect. the codes are a try only. I will post more codes later. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're misusing the shape node here: you are trying to operate on a triangle, while choosing a rectangular shape for it. If you'd want to have a triangular shape, then you'd need to use an appropriate path, not the generic rect. Once you represent a triangle by a triangular shape the touch location detection should be automatically fixed.

Comment: Triangle shape is an example to explain the problem, actually the shapes are many kinds. I have draw out the shapes, what I'm facing is how to select  the shape under its upper shape's transparent area.